How to Create a Two-Column Button Layout in ImGui Without Overlapping?
I'm trying to create a UI layout using ImGui where buttons are arranged in a two-column format. Each row should contain two buttons, and the third button should start a new row underneath the previous buttons. However, I'm encountering an issue where buttons seem to overlap or jump on each other.
    ImVec2 menuPos = { -10, 15 };
    ImVec2 menuSize = { 475.f, 775.f };

bool Option(std::string option) {
    static int buttonCounter = 0; // Counter to track button placement

    if (buttonCounter % 2 == 1) {
        ImGui::SameLine(); // Place every second button on the same line
    } else {
        ImGui::SetCursorPosX(70); // Align the first button to the right of the line
    }

    ImGui::PushStyleColor(ImGuiCol_Button, pink);
    bool result = ImGui::Button(option.c_str(), { 190, 30 });//OffsetsXY for now
    ImGui::PopStyleColor();

    buttonCounter++;

    return result;
}

void View() {
    ImGui::SetNextWindowPos(menuPos);
    ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(menuSize);

    ImGui::PushStyleColor(ImGuiCol_WindowBg, ImVec4(ImColor(0, 0, 0, 175)));
    ImGui::PushStyleColor(ImGuiCol_Border, GetCurrentFadeColor());
    ImGui::PushStyleVar(ImGuiStyleVar_WindowBorderSize, 2.f);

    if (ImGui::Begin("Background", 0, ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize)) {
       
        DrawVerticalLineFromTop(GetCurrentFadeColor(), 50, 2.f, menuSize.y);
        Option("Option1");
        Option("Option2");
        Option("Option3");
        Option("Option4");
        Option("Option5");
        Option("Option6");
        Option("Option7");
    }

    ImGui::PopStyleVar();
    ImGui::PopStyleColor(2);
    ImGui::End();
}
Expected Layout:
Option   Option
Option   Option
Option   Option
Option   ...

Instead of arranging the buttons as intended, the buttons are jumping on each other, and the layout isn't behaving as expected. After adding a third or more the button seems to overlap with all the others.
End Goal: is the use the Option method without being able to use Sameline in the view method

Moving buttonCounter out of the method seemed to fix the issue.
